# Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Yesterday, i updated my android studio to release 2.3.1.

Since then i am getting the following error

`Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid CEN header (bad signature)` while syncing the gradle project

the idea.log file shows the following:

```
2017-04-06 19:02:04,357 [  21782]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: invalid CEN header (bad signature) com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:86)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:361)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:769)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:749)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:227)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
    at     org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModuleProperties(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultPluginModuleRegistry.getPluginModules(DefaultPluginModuleRegistry.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DynamicModulesClassPathProvider.findClassPath(DynamicModulesClassPathProvider.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.<init>(DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry(GlobalScopeServices.java:224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

As some of the other threads mentioned,  have done the following so far:

1. Removed the gradle-xxx.zip file from the tools and re-downloaded the zip file, but does not seem to have worked.
2. I also created a dummy project to see if this is project specific issue but got the same issue
3. I have also removed the SDK tools and SDK from sdk manager and installed them again but got the same error

am totally stuck now and dont see a way forward :(, any suggestions would help

Comment: try restarting the android studio if not work then do File->Invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it fixed by changing the setting in the build.gradle from

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`

to

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try as @Avishek Das suggested, if it didn't work, try the following:

1. Navigate to **Users/{your name}/.gradle/wrapper/dists**
2. Check the version number in the **gradle-3.x-all** directory
3. Delete the directory then go to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and download the same gradle version **gradle-3.x-all.zip** manually and not from Android Studio.
4. After the download finishes, copy the zip file to the **Users/{your name}/.gradle/wrapper/dists** directory and unzip it.
5. Make sure that the Android Studio **preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle:** Service directory path: points to the **Users/{your name}/.gradle** directory

Comment: Looks like i have upset some android God :). 
first - my machine harddisk crashed, once i setup it up again - i used the existing android studio and it again ran the update to 2.3.1.
Since then i am not getting the error mentioned earlier but am getting the following error :

`Sync with Gradle for project 'x' failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom`
I tried the steps above, but nothing seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete Gradle folder, which is located at: **Users/{your name}/.gradle**
2. Restart android studio, it will download gradle dependency once again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>. It will open the Project structure now click on the project.
2. Change the Gradle version and android Gradle version to 1 less than the current version and click okay.
3. The Studio will start building your project.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXvsM.png)

Answer (score 0):

`flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` solved my issue

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard, I really don't know why, but `clean` and `get` solved my issue. Flutter has many cache issues, so cleaning usually solves it. I don't have any low level explanations, but this answer should stand by itself (it does not related to any other answer and in my cause, it really solved it while others didn't). Feel free to edit this answer and add more information.